# Рендеринг на стороне сервера: server-side rendering. Как?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Работаю сейчас с MeteorJS, в качестве ui-фреймворка использую ReactJS. Очень волнует вопрос рендеринга на стороне сервера - то есть нужно отдать клиенту готовый html. Сталкивался ли кто-то с подобной задачей и как её решал?

Comment: Эээ? Поиск по react server render правда ничего не дал? Это же самая популярная тема сезона

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за ваш комментарий! Честно говоря я нашел несколько пакетов, а так же прочитал, что возможно реализовать с помощью flow router, однако не очень понял, как именно/

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router-ssr. И вот тут https://kadira.io/blog/meteor/meteor-ssr-support-using-flow-router-and-react

Answer (score 1):

Meteor fast-render. Часть необходимых для отрисовки данных отправляется в JavaScript а не через DDP. Гугл охотно индексирует эту страницу. Без fr не охотно.

Comment: Откуда информация, что "гугл индексирует охотно"?. Просто я нашёл обратное на meteor hacks: "However, Fast Render does not help much with SEO ". Если fast-render действительно решает проблему индексации, то это замечательно! Но хотелось бы пруф.

Comment: На личном опыте увидел рост интереса робота и рост количества индексированных страниц. Тематика достаточно узкая, поэтому рост индексации по сравнению с предыдущими 4 месяцами заметен.
Прошу конечно учесть, что фактически это не ssr, но очень близко. Месяца два не интересовался этим вопросом, но ближайшее адекватное было что-то условно-бесплатное с подпиской для доступа ко всей кухне.

Comment: понял, спасибо за ответы! а почему решили не пользоваться пакетом spiderable ? он вроде как официально рекомендуется.

Comment: О, по моему я его просто пропустил. Позже посмотрю что к чему.